# Wordpress: Make sub-sub-category “primary” for all posts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a WORDPRESS site with many categories, sub-categories, and sub-sub-categories. Unfortunately, I have to tell the authors to always make the sub-sub-category “primary” when choosing the categories, so the specific sub-sub-category will be shown at the breadcrumb navigation for their posts. But many times, they forget.

So I’m looking for a way to automatically have the "primary" option select the last chosen subcategory for all new and existing posts.

Is this possible? Is there a script I can add to the function.php file that will help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the radio button selected:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="" checked="checked" />
```

checked="checked"  means out of the group of radio buttons this radio button is the one selected.

Comment: This is for a wordpress site. So that solution wouldn't work.